# What is the alternative to OleDB data providers?

Tags: c#, oledb, jet

I have to import data from a variety of sources: text delimited with comma, tab, custom delimiter, Excel files, SQL Server and Oracle.
The logical choice seemed to be an OleDB Connection, that would allow me treat any input as a DataSet and have very few implementation differences to worry about.

Problem is that good ol' "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" becomes obsolete.

What is the alternative to it?

Comment: Please explain where you got this absurd idea that it was obsolete.

Comment: MSDN: On "Data Access Technologies Road Map" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810810.aspx under it says: "Starting with version 2.6, MDAC no longer contains Jet components. [...] all future MDAC/WDAC releases do not contain Microsoft Jet, the Microsoft Jet OLE DB Provider, the ODBC Desktop Database Drivers, or Jet Data Access Objects (DAO). The Microsoft Jet Database Engine 4.0 components entered a state of functional deprecation and sustained engineering, and have not received feature level enhancements since becoming a part of Microsoft Windows in Windows 2000."

Comment: Thank you all for your help. The solution chosen is to keep going with Jet 4.0 in this version (time pressure is on and the code is written already) and replace them as soon as we can.

Comment: The reason MDAC doesn't include Jet is because it's been completely redundant since Windows 2000, which includes Jet and ADO as part of the OS. See @Remou's quotation below. And the deprecation is for the VS and .NET development environment, not for Access. Jet is not going away -- it's getting more and more enhancements in the most recent versions of Access (though the version of Jet that ships with Windows is frozen at Jet 4 and will not likely ever be replaced with an updated version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you think Jet is becoming obsolete?

> I consulted product team. The document
>   which you found gives a misleading
>   impression. Jet 4.0 is installed with
>   Windows 2000 and later, including
>   Vista, so it will follow the lifetime
>   of the OS through 2017 or so and even
>   longer if it ships with Longhorn.
>   Therefore, this components has been
>   removed from Microsoft Data Access
>   Components (MDAC) (2.6 and latter).
>
> We need not to worry about this
>   technology becomes obsolete.
>
> Hope this helps, please don't hesitate
>   to let me know if you have any more
>   concern. We are glad to assist you.
>
> Have a great day, Best regards,
>
> Wen Yuan Microsoft Online Community
>   Support

-- http://www.microsoft.com/communities/newsgroups/en-us/default.aspx?dg=microsoft.public.data.odbc&tid=e01c1f67-3003-48b3-8ba3-2b846c192ca1&cat=&lang=&cr=&sloc=&p=1

The document refered to is: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/271908

Comment: well, once you move to the 64bit world your SOL. Additionally if you run a 64bit app on a 64bit OS with the new `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` but for some reason the computer has 32bit Office installed your still SOL.

Answer (score 1):

There's no alternative provider framework that I know of, just different sets of APIs that provide more granularity with most of the sources OleDb caters for, minus things like WMI (which isn't actually supported anymore anyway) and [Windows Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb233505.aspx):

- [Lumenworks CSV parser](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx) (works with any delimiter)
- [Excel DataReader](http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/)
- [Various ORMs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132676/which-orm-for-net-would-you-recommend) instead of providers, though for data export/input OleDB is still easier